# pgadmin automatically display thousand seperator

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(76543210.98, '999G999G990D00');
```

This line code works well in pgadmin4, and psql.
But
It convert the numeric to text, obviously that's not i want.
Is there any possible way to change the configure settings.
So that pgadmin4 will automatically display the thousand separator.

Comment: No, there is not. If you want the number in a specific format, then what you're asking for is a string, and to_char is the correct way of doing it. If you need it to be copy/pastable as a number, it must be in a form that is valid syntax for a number (`select '123,456.78'::float` is an error, after all); that's just how it is.

Comment: I have been thinks about. In Excel, you can quickly format the number to have thousand separator.
But obviously if number is very large, thousand separator is a big issue. I am new to PostgreSQL. But I think people should do it.